# Keep application users logged in for 20 Hours

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, keep-alive

We have a asp.net + MSSQL Server DB web based application with approx 100 users. Its hosted on our intranet on IIS7.0. We are using Forms Authentication

We need to keep the users (anyone who is logged in ) to be logged in for 20 Hours exactly. Means no one should be kicked out ( session time out ) of the application before 20 Hours even if he is idle.

We tried many of the suggested approaches like web config changes etc but nothing is working.

Our main question is : Will we have to do some code changes to keep the user sessions alive for this ( or any duration). Can someone suggest or point us to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a request to the server the session timeout resets. So you can just make an ajax call to an empty HTTP handler on the server, but make sure the handler's cache is disabled, otherwise the browser will cache your handler and won't make a new request.

```
KeepSessionAlive.ashx.cs

public class KeepSessionAlive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
        }
    }

.JS:

window.onload = function () {
        setInterval("KeepSessionAlive()", 60000)
}

 function KeepSessionAlive() {
 url = "/KeepSessionAlive.ashx?";
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Shailendra. We finally solved the problem with Meta Refresh. Your solution did not work.